# Mixing two streams of audio using Java mixer

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I want to mix two streams of audio using a java mixer, and write the output into a file.

To do so, I capture the input of my two microphones by reading from the TargetDataLines of my microphone mixers:

```
    //microphone TargetDataLines
    TargetDataLine finalIn = null;
    TargetDataLine finalIn2 = null;

    Mixer.Info[] mixerInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    for (Mixer.Info info: mixerInfos){

        Mixer m = AudioSystem.getMixer(info);
        Line.Info[] lineInfos = m.getSourceLineInfo();
        System.out.println("****mixer name:" + info.getName());
        if(info.getName().equals("C920 [plughw:1,0]"))
            finalIn=(TargetDataLine) m.getLine(m.getTargetLineInfo()[0]);
        if(info.getName().equals("C920_1 [plughw:3,0]"))
            finalIn2=(TargetDataLine) m.getLine(m.getTargetLineInfo()[0]);

        for (Line.Info lineInfo:lineInfos){
            System.out.println ("\n source line info: "+lineInfo);
        }
        lineInfos = m.getTargetLineInfo();
        for (Line.Info lineInfo:lineInfos){
            System.out.println ("target line info: "+lineInfo);
        }

    }

    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(8000,16, 1, true,false);

    finalIn.open(format,2000);
    finalIn.start();
    finalIn2.open(format,2000);
    finalIn2.start();

    int numBytesRead;
    byte[] targetData = new byte[finalIn.getBufferSize() / 5];

    int numBytesRead2;
    byte[] targetData2 = new byte[finalIn2.getBufferSize() / 5];

    while (true) {
            numBytesRead = finalIn.read(targetData,0,targetData.length);
            numBytesRead2 = finalIn2.read(targetData2, 0, targetData2.length);
```

The resulting data captured from the microphones will be in `targetData`, `targetData2`. Now I want to mix these two byte arrays containing my sound samples received from the microphone into a new byte array **and I want to use another Java mixer for that**.

To do so, I create two SourceDataLine and one TargetDataLine using the following code:

```
        DataLine.Info targetInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
        DataLine.Info sourceInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
        SourceDataLine sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(sourceInfo);
        SourceDataLine sourceLine2 = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(sourceInfo);

        sourceLine.open(format,2000);
        sourceLine.start();

        sourceLine2.open(format,2000);
        sourceLine2.start();

        TargetDataLine targetLine = (TargetDataLine)        AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
        targetLine.open(format,2000);
        targetLine.start();
```

and then inside the "while" I will add:

```
    byte[] result = new byte[finalIn.getBufferSize() / 5];

    while (true) {
            numBytesRead = finalIn.read(targetData,0,targetData.length);
            numBytesRead2 = finalIn2.read(targetData2, 0, targetData2.length);

            sourceLine.write(targetData, 0, numBytesRead);
            sourceLine.write(targetData2, 0, numBytesRead2);
            targetLine.read(result, 0, numBytesRead2);
    }
```

however, while the sound is actually played properly through my headphones, the result array stays empty. 
How can I solve this problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want to store the result or play it? and if you play it do you have another soundcard? the targetline is to capture not to write so the result will not be stored; you need to clarify what you exactly want to do; do you have many soundcards?? Up to where you get the two microphones you are ok

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: I have two microphones on my 2 webcams and 1 soundcard. I need to capture the signal that goes to my speaker from my program. I want to capture the targetline associated with that mixer.

Comment: I completely dont understand the rationale: you want to mix the two inputs; but the mixer will do the mixing; why dont you let the sounds go through and capture  the mixer; it's a useless task or something that lends to hackerism; I dont understand what you want to achieve -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you have a misconception about what a Java Mixer does. I think this class was poorly named, because of my background experience as an audio engineer. In my mind, a mixer is where you combine various audio tracks. This is *not* what a Java Mixer does.

I think to do what you want to do, you need to read your two lines in parallel. For each, you will read a buffer of bytes, and will have to convert the bytes to PCM data. Then, you can add the PCM data together and convert that back to bytes and output it.

There is a good tutorial that shows how to get at the individual bytes/frames [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html). A short way down the page, there is a code example. Pay attention to the location of the comment:

```
// Here, do something useful with the audio data that's 
// now in the audioBytes array...
```

This example reads from an AudioInputStream, but the technique for getting at the individual bytes from TargetDataLines is not that different. Of course, you would be reading from both lines instead of from the single AIS. And the "useful thing" you would be doing is simply adding the PCM data on a per-frame basis, in parallel.

Once you have the summed the audio data, you could maybe use [some code I wrote](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/audio-write-generated-pcm-to-file/37029/view.html) and posted at another site, that takes a PCM stream and writes it out as a wav file. Hopefully the discussion on that page is clear enough for you to follow.

Comment: This is quite enlightening. I managed to write a a simple mixer using the link you provided. However, I was wondering if I could access a hardware mixer from Java that  would do the audio mixing for me.

Comment: Seems plausible, but I've never done it. I plan to finally try to code MIDI input reading capability for the java synth I wrote in the next month. That will be my first attempt to deal with lines other than default SourceDataLine & TargetDataLine.